# Transitioning to a specific slide

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am using PowerPoint in Office 2013 to create an advent type calendar.  It is slide 1.  How do I transition to a different slide for each day.  Example when I click on day 2 on slide 1 I want to be able to go directly to slide 3, day 3 - slide 4, etc.  Day 1 was no problem, it automatically sent me to slide 2.  Want to be able to go directly to a specific slide whenever a day is clicked in my beginning slide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229/how-do-i-hyperlink-to-a-specific-slide-of-a-ppt-file, http://www.tinyempire.com/shortnotes/files/specific_slide_in_ppt.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'Hyperlink' option in PowerPoint. Please refer the steps and use of Hyperlink option to jump from one slide to another slide on a single click.

Select a text > go to 'Insert' tab > click on 'Hyperlink' > click on "Place in This Document" > now on the right pane, select the slide to which you want to jump in. Repeat the same for all other slides. Now run the slide show and check out your results by clicking on the hyperlink text. Screenshot is for your reference.

[image]

Hope this helps.